# Rocketchip: make failing under /emulator and /vcs due to "mill: command not found"

Tags: scala, fpga, rocket-chip, mill

#### Discussed in https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/discussions/3492

<sup>Originally posted by **AnuragMalwee** September 20, 2023</sup>

Hi, I am building the rocket-chip project for the first time, and never used scala before as well.

After building the rocket-tools, the make command under $ROCKETCHIP/emulator and $ROCKETCHIP/vcs directories fail with error:

```
      cd ...../Rocket/rocket-chip && mill rocketchip.assembly
      /bin/bash: line 1: mill: command not found
      make: *** [/home/...../Rocket/rocket-chip/Makefrag:47: /home/...../Rocket/rocket-chip/out/rocketchip/assembly.dest/out.jar] Error 127
```

When trying to install mill from https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill, the cmd to run the bootstrap script recommended in their documentation fails.

$ curl -L https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/download/0.11.4/0.11.4-13-27c979 > mill && chmod +x mill

(The mill/releases dir doesn't seem to exist in the repo)

I manually copied the mill/mill script and ran it in the $ROCKETCHIP directory but I got following error:

```
anurag@anurag-vm:~/...../Rocket/rocket-chip$ ~/...../scala_mill/mill 
[build.sc] [33/49] enablePluginScalacOptions.super.mill.scalalib.ScalaModule.enablePluginScalacOptions | Downloading [1/1][build.sc] [33/49] enablePluginScalacOptions.super.mill.scalalib.ScalaModule.enablePluginScalacOptions | Downloading [1/1][build.sc] [33/49] enablePluginScalacOptions.super.mill.scalalib.ScalaModule.enablePluginScalacOptions | Downloading [1/1][build.sc] [33/49] enablePluginScalacOptions.super.mill.scalalib.ScalaModule.enablePluginScalacOptions | Downloading [1/1][build.sc] [41/49] compile 
[info] compiling 4 Scala sources to /...../Rocket/rocket-chip/out/mill-build/compile.dest/classes ...
[warn] /...../Rocket/rocket-chip/build.sc:206:155: method any2stringadd in object Predef is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Implicit injection of + is deprecated. Convert to String to call +
[warn]          |"$${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DVERILATOR -DTEST_HARNESS=VTestHarness -include VTestHarness.h -include verilator.h -include ${generator.elaborate().path / config + ".plusArgs"}")
[warn]                                                                                                                                                           ^
[warn] one warning found
[info] done compiling
[build.sc] [49/49] scriptImportGraph 
Selector cannot be empty
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Not a mill-user, but: looking at https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/tag/0.11.4, it seems like they (re?-)uploaded the corresponding files 2 days ago - maybe they forgot to update the url in script? Maybe it's worth a try to replace the url in that script by https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/download/0.11.4/0.11.4-25-ec6ebe ?

(Anyway: this seems more like an issue of mill than of rocketchip.)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page is referring to the latest development version of Mill, but not each commit is automatically released. Due to a documentation page rework in 0.11.0, there is currently no published version of the documentation addressing version 0.11.0 or 0.11.4, but only the latest development snapshot.

You can use the latest stable version [`0.11.4`](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/download/0.11.4/0.11.4) or the latest available development snapshot [`0.11.4-25-ec6ebe`](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/download/0.11.4/0.11.4-25-ec6ebe). Both are linked from the release page: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/tag/0.11.4

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
I used the command "curl -L https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/mill/releases/download/0.11.4/0.11.4 > mill && chmod +x mill" as suggested by MartinHH.
It downloads the mill script in the directory but after running it, says "A target must be provided".
Can you please help me understand this?

Also if possible, can you please provide a step-by-step process of installing the mill, so that I can confirm if I am not missing anything?

Comment: Introduction to Mill: https://mill-build.com/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html  Installation: https://mill-build.com/mill/Installation_IDE_Support.html

Comment: Yup, as per those instructions, I ran the mill script. But it says "A target must be provided".
Can you please help me understand what is this target?

Comment: Issue solved:
(ref : https://github.com/lefou/millw#installation) 

As mentioned in the millw's documentation I copied millw (renamed as mill) in root/bin dir.

(Note for noobs like me: millw documentation says to copy it in home/bin, but it should be root/bin)

Comment: "target" means a build target, which depends on your project. E.g if your project has a module `foo` and you want to run compilation, the target is "foo.compile". If you want to create the binary JAR file, the target is "foo.jar". If you just run Mill as `mill`, that it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot, Tobias for the explanation!